# Django select many to many field without raising error

Tags: python, django

Im' new to Django. I have an `Author` object (`author`) and an entry ID (`entry_id`) and I want to find out whether `author` is an author of an `Entry`.

Here's `Entry`:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

If I do

```
foo = Entry.objects.get(pk=entry_id, authors = author)
```

I get an error when the author is not an author of an entry.

What is the simpler way to do this? ultimately i just want a yes/no answer to the question of whether the author is an author for that entry. I want a valid object and not an error when the answer is no.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to your question specifications:

1. > **ultimately i just want a yes/no answer to the question of whether the author is an author for that entry.**

   Use [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists)

   From the docs:

   > Returns True if the QuerySet contains any results, and False if not.
   >   This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way
   >   possible, but it does execute nearly the same query as a normal
   >   QuerySet query.

   It will not raise any errors, it will return just `True` or `False` so you can use it inside an `if` statement. You can try something like:

   ```
   if Entry.objects.filter(pk=entry_id, authors=author).exists():
       # Magic here
   ```

   Note that I'm using `filter()` instead of `get()` because `exists()` is a `QuerySet` method (`get()` returns an object not a `QuerySet`)
2. > **I want a valid object and not an error when the answer is no.**

   Using @nabucosound approach may be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want a "valid object" so I assume you need this object to perform something with it. Thus, the lack of the object should carry performing something else, right? The most common validation done with the Django ORM for this scenario is the try/except:

```
try:
    foo = Entry.objects.get(pk=entry_id, authors=author)
except Entry.DoesNotExist:
    # Do something when object does not exist
    pass
else:
    # Do something with your foo object
```

There is nothing wrong and, in fact, Python encourages this style:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

```
entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=entry_id)
author in entry.authors.all()  # True or False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = Entry.objects.filter(pk=entry_id, authors = author).count()

if count > 0:
  #The author is an author
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check the authors of the Entry object...Try this

```
entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entry_id)
is_author = True

try:
   entry.authors.get(id=author.id)
except:
  is_author=False
```

Comment: You should really use a DoesNotExist exception here, other exceptions like DB connection or mis-typed parameters in the future could masquerade as false negatives here.